# Is it possible to reorder a child onmousedown without interrupting click event

Tags: javascript

I would like to change a child element's index on mouse down, but not interrupt the click event. Is this possible?

```
<script>

function mouseDownHandler(event) {
    var p = event.currentTarget.parentNode;
    p.appendChild(event.currentTarget);

}
</script>

<div style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 100px; width: 50px; height: 100px; background-color: red;" onmousedown="mouseDownHandler(event)" onclick="console.log('click 1')">This is a test</div>


<div style="position: absolute; left: 70px; top: 100px; width: 50px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;" onmousedown="mouseDownHandler(event)" onclick="console.log('click')">This is a test</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9d2dvcqj/

Comment: how is this interrupting the click event?

Comment: the click event isn't fired if the appendChild changes the index of the element. (Even if the mouseDown and the mouseUp are still both on the target)

Answer (score 1):

`Click` event is processed when the event `mousedown` and `mouseup` events take place over one and the same element. Accordingly, when the order of elements is changing - it does not happen and the `click` event is not invoked.

One solution - to remember on which element was `mousedown` event and compare it with the occurrence of the event `mouseup`:

```
function mouseDownHandler(event) {
    var p = event.currentTarget.parentNode;
  mouseDownHandler.mde = event.currentTarget;
    p.appendChild(event.currentTarget);
}

function mouseUpHandler(event) {
  if (event.currentTarget === mouseDownHandler.mde) {
    document.body.innerHTML += 'click<br/>';
  } else {
    mouseDownHandler.mde = null;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nrd98ujr/

Comment: I was leaning toward a similar workaround. It seems to be the way to go, but I was wondering if there was a way to possibly reorder that didn't cause an interruption in that mousedown/mouseup sequence.